# VBA: Using VLOOKUP formula with a dynamic lookup_value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to embed a VLOOKUP formula into my last column after performing formatting on a sheet. My lookup value is for a column that has the following column header: "Company State".
This is my current flow:

1. Find the Column number with the Column Header: "Company State":

   `CompanyStateColumnNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("Company State", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)`
2. Declare the range for lookup. In this case, it exists in a worksheet/workbook that is not the active workbook/worksheet. Hence, I am referencing it using ( I have already declared TZsrcRange as a Range type):

   `Set TZsrchRange = TemplateWS.Range("A:C")`
3. Now, I am trying to embed the vlookup into my last column (I found my last column in the sheet and it is stored in the variable " NewestLCol". I want to embed it into the column until the very last row (stored in variable "LastRow") :

   ```
   For x = 2 To LastRow
       Set dynamic_lookup_value = Cells(x, CompanyStateColumnNumber)
       Cells(x, NewestLCol).Formula = " =VLOOKUP(" & _
              dynamic_lookup_value.Address(0, 0) & _
            ", Templatews.Range(A:C).Address(0,0),3, FALSE)" 
   Next x
   ```
4. Now, when I run it, it doesn't embed the formula and doesn't give me a value. What could my issue be?

Comment: Please add your code, so someone can help you. Provide any error that you get.

Comment: Please consider pasting your code and explaining a bit more generally what the objective might be.

Comment: Also run your code step by step using the F8 key, ensuring your code indeed gets to the Formula assignation. If an error occurs, state its number and exact wording in the question.

Comment: Your `Cells` calls need to be qualified with a worksheet object to be sure you're referencing the sheet you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your formula assignment with this one

```
Cells(x, NewestLCol).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & _
                                dynamic_lookup_value.Address(0, 0) & _
                                "," & _
                                TZsrchRange.Address(External:=True) & _
                                ",3, FALSE)"
```

Comment: This formula actually embedded the vlookup into my cells. However, the reference was not to the other sheet (non active sheet). Is there a way to access that sheet for the lookup table? thank you so much usman!

Comment: You can replace the TZsrchRange.Address with other sheet's range reference. tell me which one you want to have

Comment: I thought I did that through Set TZsrchRange = TemplateWS.Range("A:C")? Essentially, I set TemplateWS=TemplateWB.Sheets("Sheet2") & TemplateWB=Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

Comment: You have to concatenate the full reference to the range yourself, the Address() function only returns the address of the range. something like "'[ " & file_name & "]Sheet2'!" & TZsrchRange.Address

Comment: Or use `TZsrchRange.Address(External:=True)` to return the full range reference without needing to manually construct it.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per @PatrickWynne's comment. Thanks Patrick for the helpful comment.